# Avoid warnings when C# calls my methods with arguments that cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net-5, c#-8.0, ef-core-5.0

I've read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) for C# nullable reference types.

I'm unsure how to handle the case of the framework calling my methods.

A simple EF Core example:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) 
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
     builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());    // <--- CA1062
}
```

This throws a warning CA1062:

> In externally visible method 'void DbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)', validate parameter 'builder' is non-null before using it. If appropriate, throw an ArgumentNullException when the argument is null or add a Code Contract precondition asserting non-null argument. csharp(CA1062)

I assume the framework is not going to send me null, so I see no point in checking for null.

How do I handle this scenario, namely: the framework calls my methods with arguments that cannot be null?

**EDIT**: my question differs from the linked one in that it's generic and specifically asks about C# 8's NRT feature. I only chose a related example. Thanks anyway for all those who helped.

Comment: So, you've got two assumptions - that the framework is your only caller and that the framework won't pass you null. Seems inserting a check here the *verifies* your assumptions might make sense. Do you perceive there being a large *penalty* in inserting this check?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know what you mean. But I've always resisted validating inputs sent to me by the framework. If I can't trust the framework, I'm in deep trouble. If there's a bug in the framework then I want my app to fail fast.

Comment: Can't you just specify `builder?.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());`?

Comment: If you're certain that `builder` is never null you can add `!` to tell the compiler so. Although, it *is* possible to get a null there, under extreme circumstances. The signature of [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_OnModelCreating_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_) is [protected internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal)

Comment: Wanting your app to fail fast is a very good instinct -- but if you want that you should be extra invested in a parameter null check, as it's the best way of failing fast, as opposed to having to debug an `NullReferenceException`!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Lol you make a very good point my friend, I didn't think of it that way. So you advocate for validating framework inputs?

Comment: @lonix I've added this as an answer with a link to the documentation about the _null-conditional operator_ which is what I referenced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's the first thing I tried, the null forgiving operator but it didn't silence the error. I'll look into it again, thanks.

Comment: @lonix are you sure they're framework inputs? A derived DbContext in a *different* assembly that doesn't have NREs enabled could pass a null

Comment: @lonix is your DbContext public? Does it have to be? If it has to be, can it be `sealed` so it can't be derived?

Comment: I see no reason to make any assumptions about where your parameters come from, unless your method is `private` and all the callers are trivially validated within the class itself. The framework is just written by human coders anyway, it's not infallible. I've yet to see the first code base where too much parameter validation was a bottleneck...

Comment: @JeroenMostert the method is `protected internal`. The compiler wouldn't complain about calls made from the same assembly, it would already know if the calls could pass nulls or not. That leaves derived DbContexts in *other* assemblies. That's why I assume the DbContext is public

Comment: A warning like CA1062 is matter of preference. You could disable it entirely, and the code in theory could still work fine. Even if some other code did pass you a null value, you'd eventually see _some_ exception _somewhere_. That said, the question of how to deal with CA1062 for publicly visible methods that may have a null value passed isn't unique to C# 8, nor is it a novel question. See duplicate.

Comment: I assume once more of the framework is annotated with NRT atributes, these sort of warnings will disappear?

Comment: You can [suppress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1062) a warning from this rule if you are sure that the parameter has been validated by another method call in the function.

Comment: Assuming things is the root of all evil.. especially if it involves someone else work. Never assume a parameter is not null because you trust the source.. and.. never trust a source that you don't know enough!

Comment: @lonix you haven't mentioned which version of EF Core you're using, or even that you *are* using EF Core. A later one may not produce that warning. EF Core is not part of .NET Core itself. Since you mention C# 8 I'd guess you aren't using EF Core 5 and .NET 5. There may not be any such warning there. In fact, I don't remember receiving such a warning about `OnModelCreating` in my projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just took a random example from my project. To answer your question, I'm using v5, and I chose the c#8 tag because I wanted to know about NRT. Thanks for your help, as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you can use a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.` to only invoke the `ApplyConfiguration` method if `builder` is not `null`:

```
builder?.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());?
```

From the docs:

> A null-conditional operator applies a member access, `?.`, or element
> access, `?[]`, operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates
> to non-null; otherwise, it returns null.

#### Edit following discussing in comments

I think it makes sense to include an alternative which OP is already aware of but I'll show as a more comprehensive solution.

Rather than using the null-conditional operator (which would actually hide any problem is `builder` was actually `null`), simply test `builder` at the start of the method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
    if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    ...
```

This would then be a more comprehensive way of dealing with a `null` value `builder` because an exception *will* be thrown if you receive a `null` into the method.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand you the first time! Now I see what you're getting at. This would work, but conceals the problem.

Comment: Then again, this is a compile-time only thing, so on second thought it is probably perfectly valid. I was hoping there was some NRT magic to handle this case. Is this the only way? Is this how you would do it?

Comment: Not the only way - you could test whether `builder` is `null` and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if it is?  That would probably be a more _belt and braces_ approach?

Comment: Yeah, based on your answer and the comments above seems like those are the only options. Thanks again.

Comment: I assume once more of the framework is annotated with NRT attributes, this wouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: @lonix Yes I guess that would be the case.  Do you have the option enabled on your project now?  I'm not sure what the roadmap is for including NRTs into the framework, but once it's done if the parameter is specified as non-nullable then I presume it'd be safe to assume it can't ever be null.  It's not clear to me though because the docs reference warnings and not errors in these cases...

Comment: Yea I'll just live with it till then. Frankly the more I use NRT the more sad I am that they didn't annotate more of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to disable diagnostic CA1062, if you feel that rule doesn't add any value in your scenario.

You can disable diagnostics at various levels and in different ways. Use an `.editorconfig` file to apply to a given subtree on disk. Use `#pragma` or `GlobalSuppressions.cs` to suppress specific areas in code.